# Glassfish crashes after 4 average hours running on ec2 instance

Tags: jakarta-ee, amazon-ec2, glassfish, jvm, ubuntu-12.04

I have been running some tests on a new elastic cloud instance provider and im using their free tier which offers Ubuntu ,2gb of ram for free, and other higher ram's have to be purchased, also any harddisk size can be used. Currently i used 100gb for the drive and the 2gb ram but i noticed the glassfish crashes even without deploying any app on it. I know glassfish requires a minimum of 1gb and a recommended 2gb for fair performance, i tried doing    **free -m**  on shell command to view the free memory and i noticed the server instance  uses about 1200mb of running processes which i didnt start-up, so i cleared up the cache with this ;

```
     sudo echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```

I was able to gain about 900mb plus, but later the server will be running other processes,
and increasing ram memory usage, also when i start the server after clearing the cache, it runs, but it will crash after 5 hours, only to discover the ram is been used by unknown processes.
I read up some document in a blog that says something about my jvm crashes out of heap memory, so i configured my domain.xml jvm options like this.

```
    <jvm-options>-XX:MaxPermSize=192m</jvm-options>
    <jvm-options>-XX:PermSize=64m</jvm-options>
    <jvm-options>-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled</jvm-options>
    <jvm-options>-Xmx512m</jvm-options>
    <jvm-options>-Xms512m</jvm-options>
```

Is this a proper way to configure the jvm options in a domain.xml running on a 2gb ram, also how can i permanently kill processes so i can have atleast 1.8gb of memory to run glassfish?